# Request user location via Chrome extension (Manifest V3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, geolocation, service-worker

I'm currently trying to simply request the users location for a weather widget provided by the extension's content script.

The issue I'm facing is that while this would otherwise be doable via

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);`

Using it like that in the content script requires permission of every single site the content script is running on, which in my case is **every single one** despite the extension itself featuring the geolocation permission — something I'd obviously have to avoid.

I tried requesting the geolocation via the service worker (since background scripts are deprecated in V3) but the service worker's navigator isn't featuring the geolocation to begin with and requesting the data via the content script results in the issue mentioned above, where the script uses the current webpages permission — not the one specified / requested by the extension.

Comment: Do it inside the [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document.

Comment: In the past I tried to request a permission from within the extension popup and I has not success 'cause a opened tab was needed.
Anyway It worth give offscreen doc a chance.
Let us know if it works

Comment: Will look into offscreen documents, but need to figure out how they work first. It also appears to be a ton of extra files/requests for something the chrome.offscreen example page itself states should be available for service workers in the future. MV3 really isn't ready, is it.